# How to set the a background image of a RichTextEditor in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex

I have tried setting the background image this way, but it doesn't work. Any ideas how to set the background image of a rich text control in flex as easy as possible? Thanks

```
.rte{
        ...
        backgroundImage: "assets/globe.jpg";
    }
```

and

```
<mx:RichTextEditor id="rt" 
                   ...
                   styleName="rte"
                   />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

[The docs for RichTextEditor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/RichTextEditor.html#styleSummary) show that it doesn't support a backgroundImage property, and the component is not skinnable.

Therefore, I'd suggest creating your own wrapper component, which accepts an image, like so:

```
<!-- Note: Using Canvas becuase your post indicates Flex 3, if using Flex 4, please use Group -->
<Canvas>
    <mx:Image  width="100%" height="100%" />
    <RichTextEditor />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RichTextEditor` component doesn't support background images last I checked.  What you'd want to do is create a custom RTE skin where you add an image behind the actual text, then within the skin, have the do `getStyle('backgroundImage')` and set it in a bindable private var which is then binded to the image.

That's about it.  It's either use this skin or you can always wrap your RTE within a `BitmapImage` or some other kind of component that supports background images.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that this was Flex3.  In that case, you'll need to extend your RTE component and add the Image component manually by overriding the `createChildren` function and then changing the value of the image by overriding the `updateDisplayList` function using the same `getStyle` function as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting RTE **TextArea's** *backgroundAlpha* to *0*

```
 <mx:RichTextEditor id="richTextEditor" 
        backgroundImage="@Embed('<imagepath>')" width="100%" height="100%"

        initialize="{richTextEditor.textArea.setStyle('backgroundAlpha', '0') }"
        />
```

Note:Please modify image path  and you can also set style through CSS/Style tag

Hopefully this will helps